# Isolation voltage of common mode choke, if used as coupled inductor?

Tags: inductor, communication, common-mode-choke

I have a project where I need a small coupled inductor for isolated low baudrate communication. The line is short and I don't really care if only half of signal goes through.

I need it really cheap, below $0.10 at 10k quantities. Problem is, coupled inductors don't really fit in my budget.

So I've found this common mode choke, presumably used to filter high speed communication lines:

DLM0NSM900HY2

My application requires isolation of at least 80V. I am looking at the the specs of this choke and it is not clear what voltage it will hold, and what inductance I should expect.

Can someone comment on that?

[image: datasheet]

Comment: How about the lines that say 'Rated Voltage 5 V', and 'Withstanding Voltage 12.5 V' ?

Comment: What is the minimum inductance you can work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My application requires isolation of at least 80V. I am looking at the
> the specs of this choke and it is not clear what voltage it will hold,
> and what inductance I should expect.*
>
> *Can someone comment on that?*

The [data sheet](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8799424610334/EFLD0009.pdf?1634047222000) says that the withstand voltage is a measly 12.5 volts: -

[image]

So I thought I'd better dig a little deeper and look to see how they test that: -

[image]

And, it is what it is so, if you want an isolation capability of 80 volts I'd definitely look for a better alternative. Given that it is nowhere near your requirement it's pointless trying to figure out its inductance.

Comment: Yes I saw those specs and could not believe it is only 12V. I thought it may be some kind of noise amplitude or whatever. But looks like it really is 12V.

Any ideas on what inductance it may have? Or if I can calculate it somehow from other specs, without buying and measuring.

Comment: It's pointless trying to figure it out if it can't handle the voltage.

Comment: not really, as this, similar choke can withstand 125V.
https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic/EXC-34CE900U?qs=MNPzkKEzRtQUpS18S%252BCeqA%3D%3D
 
Any chance of knowing inductance without ordering and waiting?
I'd need 10-50uH.

Edit: frequency and impedance is given for this one, so I'll figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: At least it has graphs but, I estimate it to be around 150 nH and much lower than what you want I suspect.